# how to display month names in russian in cakephp

Tags: php, date, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.x

I need to display month names in Russian, is it enough to change the `defaultLocale` value?

`'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'ru_RU')`

This doesnt seem to work, because `<?= h($news->created->format('d F, Y')) ?>` displays `01 October, 2016`

Do I need to make changes anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the locale is enough in terms of configuration changes required, however in order to get localized output, you have to use the proper locale aware formatting methods, that is `i18nFormat()`.

It should be noted that this method uses ICU formatting patterns, not the standard PHP ones, see: **https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax**

So long story short, to get a localized variant of `d F, Y`, use

```
$news->created->i18nFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy')
```

For `ru_RU` this should return `01 октября, 2016`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Formatting > Time::i18nFormat](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake%5CI18n%5CTime::i18nFormat)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\DateFormatTrait::i18nFormat()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.I18n.DateFormatTrait.html#_i18nFormat)**